# Calling same GET request again not return updated data after PUT

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, use-http

I called `fetchdata()` function inside useEffect and also after updating the data using `onUpdate()`. The `fetchdata()` always gives the same result after the update. But it shows updated data after refreshing the page and also the API is also updating successfully after calling `onUpdate()` function. Please give me a solution.

```
const id = useParams().id;
const [hallsLabs, setHallsLabs] = useState('');
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const { get, post, put, del, response } = useFetch(process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_BASE_URL);

useEffect(() => {
    fetchdata();
}, [])

const fetchdata = async () =>{
    await get(`/halls-labs/${id}`).then(result => {
        if (response.ok) {
            console.log(result);
            setHallsLabs(result);
        } else {
            console.log('error', result.msg);
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('error', err);
    })
}

const onUpdate = async (event) => {
    setLoading(true);
    console.log(event);
    await put(`/halls-labs/update/${id}`, event).then(result => {
        if (response.ok) {
            console.log('updated');
            fetchdata();
            setLoading(false);
        } else {
            console.log('error', result.msg);
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('error', err);
    })
}
```

**Here's an Image of the console.**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBik5.png

Comment: can you add some logs for reference?

Comment: @SunilKumar Here's an image of the console : https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBik5.png

Comment: do you have any backend/database logs captured? can you see the data in DB updated?

Comment: @SunilKumar yes DB updated as soon as I update it through the frontend. but react don't fetch the get request again. I'm using a spring-boot backend.

Comment: @SunilKumar thank you for the support. its done, It fixed after using axios to fetch data. don't know what is the problem with use-http module.

Comment: I assume it must be something to do with the way `async-await` method invocations.